# What is the proper way to process the user-trigger events in Django?

Tags: python, django, message-queue

For example, I have a blog based on `Django` and I already have several functions for users: `login`、`edit_profile`、`share`.

But now I need to implement a mission system.

1. User logins, reward `10 score` per day
2. User completes his profile, reward `20 score`
3. User shares my blogs, reward `30 score`

I don't want to mix reward code with normal functions code. So I decide to use `message queue`. Pseudo code may look like:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    nickname = ...
    desc = ...
    user.save(...)
    action.send(sender='edit_profile', payload={'user_id': user.id})
    return Response(...)
```

And the reward can subscribe this action

```
@receiver('edit_profile')
def edit_profile_reward(payload):
    user_id = payload['user_id']
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    mission, created = Mission.objects.get_or_create(user=user, type='complete_profile')
    if created:
         user.score += 20
         user.save()
```

But I don't know if this is the right way. If so, what `message queue` should I use? `django-channel` / `django-q` or something else?
If not, what is the best practice?

Comment: Your sender/receiver method seems like a good idea. Probably easier to implement than the method I would use (i.e., database trigger coupled to and handled by a separate service). Have you tried to implement the method you've described? If so, what were the results?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm still thinking about an appropriate approach, lol.

Comment: Have you considered [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals)? You can use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) to run your score logic after profile is updated. Otherwise I would start a monitoring thread upon app start (perhaps with a middleware) which would consume messages put in a queue. I would use Python's built in Queue and put messages in it in my view function.

Comment: Yes, I know `signal`. But it is synchronous and that is why I mentioned `django-q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for Async queue, you will need a combo of Redis and workers.

One of the most common libraries, and simplest, out there for this is [RQ Workers](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/)

Implementation is simple, but you will need to run the rq-workers as a separate app.

It also allows you to implement different queues with different priorities. I use these for things like sending emails or things that need to be updated without making the user wait (logs, etc...)

[Django-Q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is another good solution with the advantage of being able to use your current database as the queue - but also works with Redis et al...

Finally, [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/) is the grandaddy of them all. You can have scheduled jobs with Celeray as well as async jobs. A bit more complex but good solution.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking to do is fairly normal when it comes to cuing tasks with Django or any Python framework for that matter. While there is no "right" way to do this, I personally would recommend going with Redis. Considering that you would have many users receiving points this would make your querying really fast.

You can naturally makes this up with Celery to make your own Stack. Everything will be done in RAM, which will be helpful for such repetitive tasks.

You can take a look at [Redis for Django over here](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis).

You would essentially need to include this as a caching server in your settings.

In whichever file you implement cuing, remember to add the following:

```
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
```

I would agree that initially setting this up seems daunting, but trust me on this it is a great way to cue any task quickly and efficiently. Give it a shot! You will find it extremely useful in all of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous/deferred execution of tasks/jobs you can use

Celery: https://github.com/celery/celery/

Django:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html